# What is the geometric reason for the negative sign in front of the scalar product defining the second fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry

This is bound to have some easy explanation in terms of aligning the differential of the normal vector to the surface $S$ with the direction of the vector taken into the quadratic $\vec v$, but I am not sure why. Since it is a definition, the temptation is to just take it at face value, but it has to have an explanation.

$$II_p=\color{red}-\langle dNp(\vec v), v \rangle$$

---

I found a [good explanation on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/e9oiy3/how_do_i_interpret_the_first_and_second/), and I will keep the question open to see if I get better answers, although this is really good:

> The second fundamental form measures the extrinsic curvature. The
>   actual definition is a bit cumbersome, but interpretation is very
>   geometric. The value on a unit vector (unit with respect to the first
>   fundamental form) is how much the surface bends in that direction.
>   Larger number means more bending. The sign tells whether the surface
>   bends upwards or downwards - for this you need to choose which side of
>   the surface is a "top side" and "bottom side", mathematically this is
>   a choice of the unit normal vector field. Positive signs says that
>   standing on the top side it looks like $-x^2$ (a hill), negative signs
>   says that standing on the top side it looks like $x^2$ (a valley).
>
> If the second fundamental form is positive definite or negative
>   definite, the surface looks locally like a portion of a sphere (and
>   the definiteness just tells you whether the unit normal points inside
>   or outside). If there exist both positive and negative directions,
>   then the surface locally looks like a saddle surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no intrinsic geometric way to distinguish the sign, as you can change the direction of the unit normal field $N$. But positive normal curvature means that the the curve is bending *toward* $N$ rather than away from $N$.

The main reason for the negative sign is to remove a negative sign from the second fundamental form when you compute it with second-order partial derivatives using a parametrization. That is, if you have a parametrization $\mathbf x(u,v)$, then, for example,
$$\text{II}_p(\mathbf x_u,\mathbf x_u) = \mathbf x_{uu}\cdot N.$$
This is how one usually computes the matrix $\text{II}$. The negative sign arises because when we differentiate $\mathbf x_u\cdot N = 0$, we get $$\mathbf x_{uu}\cdot N = -N_u\cdot \mathbf x_u = -dN_p(\mathbf x_u)\cdot \mathbf x_u.$$

Comment: Thank you! Right... differentiating $\langle \vec x_u, N\rangle=0$ we get $\langle \vec x_{uu}, N\rangle + \langle \vec x_u, N_u\rangle=0,$ which means that $\langle x_{uu},N\rangle = -\langle dN_p(\vec x_u), \vec x_u\rangle..$